# Is it possible to compile c++ using Clang only on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, clang

I really tried a lot. Clang does not come with standard C++ includes, and obviously can not find them :

```
clang++ file.cpp -o file.out
C:\Folder\file.cpp:1:11: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include  <iostream>
          ^
1 error generated.
```

Passing the mingw includes by arguments, it returns another error:

```
clang++ -target x86_64-w64-mingw32 C:\Folder\file.cpp -IC:\MinGW\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++ -IC:\MinGW\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\x86_64-w64-mingw32 -IC:\MinGW\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include -o C:\Folder\file.out -std=c++11
clang++.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I use `-c` it does not use the linker and also not generate an executable file.

Edit : I'm running on windows

Comment: What are you executing this from, and are you sure it can consume DOS-style paths?

Comment: Which ones do I use?

Comment: Follow a guide for installing clang on windows

Comment: The LLVM site only shows how to install using visual studio

Comment: Following clang installation guides is only useful if backend is msvc

Answer (score 1):

Run your commands from "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017", or something similar. It will setup some required env vars for you.